# Обратная совместимость DirectX

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, directx

Всем добрый день! Начал учить разработку с помощью DirectX по книге. Книга довольно старая и примеры используемые в ней написаны на DirectX 7 версии если я не ошибаюсь. Так вот запустить данные примеры мне не удается экран завален разного рода ошибками. У меня установлен DX 12. И меня интересует несколько вопросов.

1. Есть ли обратная совместимость DX ?
2. Если совместимости нет то мне нужно установить 7 DX что бы примеры работали. Возможно ли установить 2 версии DX на одном пк ??

Comment: DirectX 7 может быть интересен разве что любителям поковырять древние игры, так что книжку можете смело выкидывать. Изучать имеет смысл только DX 11 / DX 12. Directx версий 9 - 12 уже включен в Windows SDK, который идет с VS

Comment: @VTT я не любитель ковырять древние игры но ничего более нового в этом направлении я не нашел. А начинать учиться с чего то нужно. Можете посоветовать достойную литературу по игрострою на DX 12 ?? Я бы с удовольствием прочитал.

Comment: Можно начать с [DirectX 11 Rastertek Tutorials](http://www.rastertek.com/tutdx11.html). Предусловия включают уверенное владение С / C++, знакомство с технологией COM, знание линейной алгебры.

Comment: @VTT Благодарю за ссылку любая информация будет полезна. Обязательно ознакомлюсь с ней. Ну а по поводу моих двух вопросов что вы можете сказать?

Comment: Каких именно вопросов? Обратной совместимости нет (точнее нет совместимости между интерфейсами, но есть частичная между шейдерами). На Windows обычно присутствуют сразу все версии начиная с 7 - 8

Comment: @VTT А как проверить какие версии DX у меня установлены ?? с помощью консоли я смог вызвать только DX 12.

Comment: Я же написал, все, начиная с 7-8, уже есть. хз, как вы там вызываете DX12 из консоли

Comment: @VTT Прошу прощения. Еще один вопрос. Получается что программы когда то написанные на DX 7 и скомпилированные я смогу запускать но если я попробую написать тот же функционал теми же функциями он у меня будет сыпать ошибками. Я правильно понял ??

Comment: Нет. По идее можно вполне писать под какой-нибудь DirectX 8. Но зачем?

Comment: @VTT я просто хочу изучить примеры из книги но не понимаю как мне их запустить. Хочу понять сам принцип. Скомпилированный пример запускается и работает уже готовый. Но скомпилировать самостоятельно у меня не получается и я не понимаю с чем это связано если есть совместимость.

Comment: Так создайте вопрос описывающий конкретную проблему... С конкретным кодом и конкретными ошибками

Answer (score -1):

В общем. После долгих ковыряний я нашел ответ на свой вопрос. Дело все в том что в книжных примерах используется библиотека ddraw в последней версии SDK DirectX этой библиотеке нет. По этому у меня не компилируется пример. И по этому и возникли подобные вопросы. Спасибо всем кто отозвался.